# TestRPC crashing

Tags: truffle, testrpc, testing

When I run my Truffle test suite locally with testrpc, testrpc sporadically fails with this error:

```
eth_call
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:61262
    db.get(key, {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at dbGet (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:61262:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:17720:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:24532:20
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:24613:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:24625:29
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:24395:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:17725:7
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:61267:9
    at dispatchError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:31665:35)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:23916:14
```

This only happens about 20% of the time and at different parts of my tests, but it's pretty annoying.  Anyone encounter this as well?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/340
Seems like this is still not resolved